# Why can't upstart start cups or mysql?

Tags: upstart, printing

For some reason I can't start mysql or cups using upstart i.e. "service cups start" results in "start: Job failed to start". How can I debug this? I also tried resintalling using synaptic, but that failed also, since it tries to start process also. This is with 11.04

Comment: Is there some detail in the logfiles?

Comment: nope nothing I can see in the logs.

Comment: Long shot I know but... MySQL gives this message when you remove /etc/mysql/my.cnf.

Comment: Ok I found some more info: seems apparmor is having some problems.  this is in boot.log

`AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.cupsd in /etc/apparmor.d/tunables/global at line 17: Could not open 'tunables/proc'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem.  The file `/etc/apparmor.d/tunables/proc` was missing, so I copied it from my backup and now it works.

Comment: Nice one! I was close with a missing my.cnf (but I knew that did not cover cups) :D Do upvote and accept your answer!